# Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined with ga('require', 'ec')

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

My site tracks pageviews using Google Tag Manager，and loads the enhanced e-commerce plugin in some pages using `ga('require', 'ec')`,  but there is an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined

**Code Snippet:**

```
ga('require', 'ec');
function onProductClick(product, url, key) {
    ga('ec:addProduct', {
        'id': "'" + product.product_id + "'",                        
        'name': product.model_name,                                  
        'category': product.series_name + '/' + product.dealer_name, 
        'brand': product.brand_name,                                 
        'variant': product.model_name,                               
        'position': key                                              
    });
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Did you by chance change the global function name in the advanced settings (maybe you meant to change the tracker name, which would be necessary for this to work, and hit the wrong setting) ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff I didn't change the  global function name, but my site is https, can https  affect gtm's load?

Comment: No, https does not affect GTM. It might be that your code is run before the Analytics tag is loaded. I think it would be better if you created your e-commerce tracking via GTM (i.e. pushing the values to the datalayer and then send the information via a GTM analytics tag).

Comment: @EikePierstorff The gtm snippet is in the <head>, and my code is in the <body>, I don't understand why my code is run before the Analytics tag is loaded.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

GA is loading after this script runs.

GTM is asynchronous, so the tags included in it are not guaranteed to run before  inline scripts are run.

You could add this script as an HTML tag in GTM and set the Universal Analytics tag as a requirement for it, or [add some more script](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/ga-snippet-and-ga-gtm-tag-on-the-same-page/#4) to your page's head.

```
<script>
  window['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = 'ga';
  window['ga'] = window['ga'] || function() {
    (window['ga'].q = window['ga'].q || []).push(arguments)
  };
</script>
```

[(Source)](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/ga-snippet-and-ga-gtm-tag-on-the-same-page/#4)